# Modify Android Market App

Tags: android, google-play

Is it possible to modify the Android Market application (on my device)?

I want to add an extra button to the Market with my own custom functionality.

If it is possible, could this be exported to other users via the Market?

Many thanks,

Stephen

Answer (score 3):

No, this is **not** possible at all.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't say it's *impossible* because you could pull it off a rooted device, unzip it, and start modifying the dex code at the byte level, but it's really, really hard and you'd never get it approved for the Market.  That said, if you did succeed, you could offer it on your own website.

Comment: Considering the OP had to _ask_, I went with the _feasibly impossible_ answer :) Anyway +1 for the details.

Comment: @MarvinPinto Definitely true ;-)